# JobScheduler and JobIntentService

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am working on an app that supports Android API version 21 and above. Most of my background tasks have been designed with JobScheduler introduced in API 21.

I have recently come across JobIntentService introduces in API 26. The documentation says "When running on Android O or later, the work will be dispatched as a job via JobScheduler.enqueue. When running on older versions of the platform, it will use Context.startService."

What I want to understand is, why android is using JoScheduler only from API 26 and not from API 21. Is there a difference in JobScheduler on API 26 and above from that of the one introduced in API 21. Do I need to change any code to improve efficiency/avoid mistakes, converting my background jobs to use JobIntentService instead of Job Schedulers. I guess I do not understand the intention of what JobIntentService is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I do not understand the intention of what JobIntentService is trying to achieve

`JobIntentService` is meant to be a replacement for the `IntentService`/`WakefulBroadcastReceiver` combination, for background tasks that might take more than a minute (but less than ten) and for which you do not wish to use a foreground service.

> why android is using JoScheduler only from API 26 and not from API 21

Only Google can answer that, which is why questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are not good for Stack Overflow.

Note that the "more than a minute" issue arises with the background limitations on API Level 26+; on previous versions, there was no such limit.

> Is there a difference in JobScheduler on API 26 and above from that of the one introduced in API 21

There have been changes, including some extensions that enable `JobIntentService` to work.

> Do I need to change any code to improve efficiency/avoid mistakes, converting my background jobs to use JobIntentService instead of Job Schedulers

I do not know why you would switch from your own `JobService` to `JobIntentService`. `JobIntentService` is a replacement for `IntentService`, not for `JobService`.